# Cannot upload file in Codeigniter when created dynamic form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to upload file to a local folder using codeigniter, there are multiple forms and file input fields generated which have there own id, when user clicks on any one then the id of that particular field has to be passed to controller from ajax and then its name will be created by appending that id (for eg. "input_image"+1 will be input_image1 now i have to upload it from the controller my code is as follows:

> View

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
function sendVideoData(frm_id)
{

    var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("post_video_"+frm_id));

    // make the AJAX request
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"dashboard/do_upload",
        data: data+'&form_id='+frm_id,
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data", 
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
        },

    });

    return false;
}
</script>
<?php for($i=0;$i<=10 (or it can be more); $i++)
  {
<form name="post_video" id="post_video_<?=$row1['id']?>" method="post" onsubmit="return sendVideoData(<?=$row1['id']?>)">           
    <input type="file" name="save_movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" id="movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" /> 
    <input name="type_lecture_id" class="get_lecture_id" id="get_lecture_id_<?=$row1['id']?>" value="<?=$row1['id']?>" type="hidden"/>
    <input type="button" class="postbtn" id="submit_movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" value="Upload Video File"/>
</form>
  }
```

> Controller:

```
    function do_upload()
    {
    $formid=$_POST['form_id'];
  $file_name = 'save_movie_'.$formid;
  $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
  $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
  $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
  $this->upload->do_upload($file_name);
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    }
```

upload folder is in root directory

Answer (score 0):

After getting the file name using ajax in controller do like this

```
     public function file_upload(){
                 $formid=$_POST['form_id'];
                 $file_name = 'save_movie_'.$formid;
                 $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
  $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
  $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
  $this->upload->do_upload($file_name)
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
}
```

This will work for multiple and single upload for more read this http://w3code.in/2015/09/upload-file-using-codeigniter/

Comment: Thanks Ricky but i have to upload one file at a time. Only thing is that there are many fields on the screen to upload the file but with different id, as my html section in my question.

Comment: The content are being dynamically generated.

Comment: In which format you are getting the file name in controller?

Comment: if you are getting like this (image1,image2.image3,..) the explode it first and then count and insert with the code I have given you

Comment: I am passing it through ajax as post data. u can see in my question

Comment: but Ricky the user can upload one image at a time.

Comment: Ricky i have updated my html form code. Please see to it. There is a for loop that will display data according to the data found from the database.

Comment: Ricky i have checked but the image is not uploaded. I have updated the code in my question that i am using. Please try to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
if (empty($_FILES['imagefile']['name'][0])) {          
            return FALSE;
        }
```